# React - get textarea's value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using React with Redux, I want to dispatch an action with an argument which will be typed by user in textarea, so I'm introducing a function with a dispatch:

```
sendMessage(text) {
  this.props.dispatch(sendMessage(text))
}
```

And then I'm triggering the dispatch with proper argument on textarea blur:

```
<textarea name="message" onBlur={() => sendMessage(this.value)}></textarea>
```

The question is: how do I get textarea's value? `this.value` returns my component instead of textarea. When I try to bind(this) like:

```
<textarea name="message" onBlur={() => sendMessage(this.value).bind(this)}></textarea>
```

I'm getting

> Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

How can I access the `textarea.value`?

Comment: I think you need to share more context

Comment: if sendMessage is internal function of the component use `this.sendMessage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your callback receives `event` object as the first parameter

you can use it like this:

```
<textarea name="message" onBlur={ev => sendMessage(ev.target.value)}></textarea>
```